# Ubuntu Tweak Shutting Down Itself

Tags: 12.04, ubuntu-tweak

I am using 12.04 LTS. This morning when I tried to clean up some unnecessary items using Janitor in Ubuntu Tweak (Firefox cache & Thumbnail cache), it was suddenly shutting down/closed by itself. Right in the middle of cleaning process, after I input my password.

Could someone advise me on this issue? I have tried to googling this and also use the Search option in this site but end up with no result. Thanks.

As requested by 'green7', I attached the result that came in terminal when executing Ubuntu Tweak:

```
ibu@ibu-G31M-ES2L-130102:~$ ubuntu-tweak
[Launcher][DEBUG] Distribution: Ubuntu 12.04 precise
Application: Ubuntu Tweak 0.8.4-0~bzr1954+20130416~precise1
Desktop:ubuntu (ubuntu-tweak:59)
[gtk][DEBUG] <function post_ui at 0x9038b8c>: (debug.py:182)
[gtk][DEBUG]    args-1: <function _confirm_deps at 0x9347aac> (debug.py:184)
[gtk][DEBUG] <function post_ui at 0x9038b8c>: (debug.py:182)
[gtk][DEBUG]    args-1: <function _on_error at 0x9347d14> (debug.py:184)
[gtk][DEBUG] <function post_ui at 0x9038b8c>: (debug.py:182)
[gtk][DEBUG]    args-1: <function on_find_object at 0x9361374> (debug.py:184)
[gtk][DEBUG] <function post_ui at 0x9038b8c>: (debug.py:182)
[gtk][DEBUG]    args-1: <function on_scan_finished at 0x936141c> (debug.py:184)
[gtk][DEBUG] <function post_ui at 0x9038b8c>: (debug.py:182)
[gtk][DEBUG]    args-1: <function on_scan_error at 0x936148c> (debug.py:184)
[gtk][DEBUG] <function post_ui at 0x9038b8c>: (debug.py:182)
[gtk][DEBUG]    args-1: <function on_plugin_object_cleaned at 0x93615dc> (debug.py:184)

(ubuntu-tweak:4697): GConf-WARNING **: : You can't use a GConfEngine that has an active GConfClient wrapper object. Use GConfClient API instead.

(ubuntu-tweak:4697): GConf-WARNING **: : You can't use a GConfEngine that has an active GConfClient wrapper object. Use GConfClient API instead.
Checking if settings need to be migrated ...no
Checking if internal files need to be migrated ...no
Backend     : gconf
Integration : true
Profile     : unity
Adding plugins
Initializing core options...done
[gtk][DEBUG] <function post_ui at 0x9038b8c>: (debug.py:182)
[gtk][DEBUG]    args-1: <function _load_module at 0x9444bc4> (debug.py:184)
[CommonSetting][DEBUG] Loading schema value for: com.ubuntu-tweak.tweak/tweaks (common.py:107)
[CommonSetting][DEBUG]  Loading override (common.py:94)
[CommonSetting][DEBUG] Try to get type for value: [('name', 'recently-used'), ('type', 'as')] (common.py:147)
[CommonSetting][DEBUG] Try to get type for value: [('name', 'clips'), ('type', 'as')] (common.py:147)
[CommonSetting][DEBUG] Try to get type for value: [('name', 'tweaks'), ('type', 'as')] (common.py:147)
[CommonSetting][DEBUG] Try to get type for value: [('name', 'admins'), ('type', 'as')] (common.py:147)
[CommonSetting][DEBUG] Try to get type for value: [('name', 'auto-backup'), ('type', 'b')] (common.py:147)
[CommonSetting][DEBUG] Try to get type for value: [('name', 'window-size'), ('type', '(ii)')] (common.py:147)
[CommonSetting][DEBUG] Try to get type for value: [('name', 'last-clip-location'), ('type', 's')] (common.py:147)
[CommonSetting][DEBUG] Try to get type for value: [('name', 'appcenter-has-update'), ('type', 'b')] (common.py:147)
[CommonSetting][DEBUG] Try to get type for value: [('name', 'appcenter-version'), ('type', 's')] (common.py:147)
[GSetting][DEBUG] Got the schema_default: [] for key: com.ubuntu-tweak.tweak.tweaks (gsettings.py:21)
[app][DEBUG] Loading modules... (main.py:180)
[ModuleLoader][INFO] Loading system modules for tweaks... (__init__.py:54)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] Try to load module: workarounds (__init__.py:159)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] is_supported_distro (__init__.py:238)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] Try to load module: misc (__init__.py:159)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] is_supported_distro (__init__.py:238)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] Try to load module: unity (__init__.py:159)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] is_supported_distro (__init__.py:238)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] Try to load module: sound (__init__.py:159)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] is_supported_distro (__init__.py:238)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] Try to load module: nautilus (__init__.py:159)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] is_supported_distro (__init__.py:238)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] Try to load module: lovewallpaperhd (__init__.py:159)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] is_supported_distro (__init__.py:238)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] Try to load module: fonts (__init__.py:159)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] is_supported_distro (__init__.py:238)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] Try to load module: icons (__init__.py:159)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] is_supported_distro (__init__.py:238)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] Try to load module: session (__init__.py:159)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] is_supported_distro (__init__.py:238)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] Try to load module: window (__init__.py:159)
[GconfSetting][DEBUG] Got the schema_default: None for key: /apps/metacity/general/button_layout (gconfsettings.py:27)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] is_supported_distro (__init__.py:238)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] Try to load module: theme (__init__.py:159)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] is_supported_distro (__init__.py:238)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] Try to load module: workspace (__init__.py:159)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] is_supported_distro (__init__.py:238)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] Try to load module: loginsettings (__init__.py:159)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] is_supported_distro (__init__.py:238)
[ModuleLoader][INFO] Loading user extensions for tweaks... (__init__.py:64)
[app][INFO] Creating ModuleButton: <class 'fonts.Fonts'> (main.py:51)
[app][INFO] Creating ModuleButton: <class 'misc.Misc'> (main.py:51)
[app][INFO] Creating ModuleButton: <class 'sound.Sound'> (main.py:51)
[app][INFO] Creating ModuleButton: <class 'theme.Theme'> (main.py:51)
[app][INFO] Creating ModuleButton: <class 'loginsettings.LoginSettings'> (main.py:51)
[app][INFO] Creating ModuleButton: <class 'session.Session'> (main.py:51)
[app][INFO] Creating ModuleButton: <class 'icons.Icons'> (main.py:51)
[app][INFO] Creating ModuleButton: <class 'lovewallpaperhd.LovewallpaperHD'> (main.py:51)
[app][INFO] Creating ModuleButton: <class 'unity.Unity'> (main.py:51)
[app][INFO] Creating ModuleButton: <class 'window.Window'> (main.py:51)
[app][INFO] Creating ModuleButton: <class 'workspace.Workspace'> (main.py:51)
[app][INFO] Creating ModuleButton: <class 'nautilus.Nautilus'> (main.py:51)
[app][INFO] Creating ModuleButton: <class 'workarounds.Workarounds'> (main.py:51)
[CommonSetting][DEBUG] Loading schema value for: com.ubuntu-tweak.tweak/admins (common.py:107)
[GSetting][DEBUG] Got the schema_default: [] for key: com.ubuntu-tweak.tweak.admins (gsettings.py:21)
[app][DEBUG] Loading modules... (main.py:180)
[ModuleLoader][INFO] Loading system modules for admins... (__init__.py:54)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] Try to load module: userdir (__init__.py:159)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] is_supported_distro (__init__.py:238)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] Try to load module: templates (__init__.py:159)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] is_supported_distro (__init__.py:238)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] Try to load module: filetypemanager (__init__.py:159)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] is_supported_distro (__init__.py:238)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] Try to load module: sourceeditor (__init__.py:159)
[gtk][DEBUG] <function post_ui at 0x9038b8c>: (debug.py:182)
[gtk][DEBUG]    args-1: <function process_data at 0x954caac> (debug.py:184)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] is_supported_distro (__init__.py:238)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] Try to load module: shortcuts (__init__.py:159)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] is_supported_distro (__init__.py:238)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] Try to load module: scripts (__init__.py:159)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] is_supported_distro (__init__.py:238)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] Try to load module: desktoprecovery (__init__.py:159)
[gtk][DEBUG] <function post_ui at 0x9038b8c>: (debug.py:182)
[gtk][DEBUG]    args-1: <function process_data at 0x961ed14> (debug.py:184)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] is_supported_distro (__init__.py:238)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] Try to load module: appcenter (__init__.py:159)
[CommonSetting][DEBUG] Loading schema value for: com.ubuntu-tweak.tweak/appcenter-has-update (common.py:107)
[GSetting][DEBUG] Got the schema_default: False for key: com.ubuntu-tweak.tweak.appcenter-has-update (gsettings.py:21)
[CommonSetting][DEBUG] Loading schema value for: com.ubuntu-tweak.tweak/appcenter-version (common.py:107)
[GSetting][DEBUG] Got the schema_default:  for key: com.ubuntu-tweak.tweak.appcenter-version (gsettings.py:21)
[gtk][DEBUG] <function post_ui at 0x9038b8c>: (debug.py:182)
[gtk][DEBUG]    args-1: <function on_have_update at 0x9632534> (debug.py:184)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] is_supported_distro (__init__.py:238)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] Try to load module: quicklists (__init__.py:159)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] is_supported_distro (__init__.py:238)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] Try to load module: sourcecenter (__init__.py:159)
[CommonSetting][DEBUG] Loading schema value for: com.ubuntu-tweak.tweak/appcenter-has-update (common.py:107)
[GSetting][DEBUG] Got the schema_default: False for key: com.ubuntu-tweak.tweak.appcenter-has-update (gsettings.py:21)
[CommonSetting][DEBUG] Loading schema value for: com.ubuntu-tweak.tweak/appcenter-version (common.py:107)
[GSetting][DEBUG] Got the schema_default:  for key: com.ubuntu-tweak.tweak.appcenter-version (gsettings.py:21)
[gtk][DEBUG] <function post_ui at 0x9038b8c>: (debug.py:182)
[gtk][DEBUG]    args-1: <function on_have_update at 0x964f4fc> (debug.py:184)
[CommonSetting][DEBUG] Loading schema value for: com.ubuntu-tweak.apps/disable-warning (common.py:107)
[CommonSetting][DEBUG] Try to get type for value: [('name', 'disable-warning'), ('type', 'b')] (common.py:147)
[CommonSetting][DEBUG] Try to get type for value: [('name', 'apps-can-update'), ('type', 'b')] (common.py:147)
[CommonSetting][DEBUG] Try to get type for value: [('name', 'apps-version'), ('type', 's')] (common.py:147)
[CommonSetting][DEBUG] Try to get type for value: [('name', 'sources-can-update'), ('type', 'b')] (common.py:147)
[CommonSetting][DEBUG] Try to get type for value: [('name', 'sources-version'), ('type', 's')] (common.py:147)
[GSetting][DEBUG] Got the schema_default: False for key: com.ubuntu-tweak.apps.disable-warning (gsettings.py:21)
[CommonSetting][DEBUG] Loading schema value for: com.ubuntu-tweak.apps/sources-can-update (common.py:107)
[GSetting][DEBUG] Got the schema_default: False for key: com.ubuntu-tweak.apps.sources-can-update (gsettings.py:21)
[CommonSetting][DEBUG] Loading schema value for: com.ubuntu-tweak.apps/sources-version (common.py:107)
[GSetting][DEBUG] Got the schema_default:  for key: com.ubuntu-tweak.apps.sources-version (gsettings.py:21)
[gtk][DEBUG] <function post_ui at 0x9038b8c>: (debug.py:182)
[gtk][DEBUG]    args-1: <function show_warning at 0x9653454> (debug.py:184)
[gtk][DEBUG] <function post_ui at 0x9038b8c>: (debug.py:182)
[gtk][DEBUG]    args-1: <function upgrade_sources at 0x96535a4> (debug.py:184)
[gtk][DEBUG] <function post_ui at 0x9038b8c>: (debug.py:182)
[gtk][DEBUG]    args-1: <function on_have_update at 0x9653614> (debug.py:184)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] is_supported_distro (__init__.py:238)
[ModuleLoader][INFO] Loading user extensions for admins... (__init__.py:64)
[app][INFO] Creating ModuleButton: <class 'appcenter.AppCenter'> (main.py:51)
[app][INFO] Creating ModuleButton: <class 'sourcecenter.SourceCenter'> (main.py:51)
[app][INFO] Creating ModuleButton: <class 'desktoprecovery.DesktopRecovery'> (main.py:51)
[app][INFO] Creating ModuleButton: <class 'quicklists.QuickLists'> (main.py:51)
[app][INFO] Creating ModuleButton: <class 'scripts.Scripts'> (main.py:51)
[app][INFO] Creating ModuleButton: <class 'shortcuts.Shortcuts'> (main.py:51)
[app][INFO] Creating ModuleButton: <class 'templates.Templates'> (main.py:51)
[app][INFO] Creating ModuleButton: <class 'userdir.UserDir'> (main.py:51)
[app][INFO] Creating ModuleButton: <class 'filetypemanager.FileTypeManager'> (main.py:51)
[app][INFO] Creating ModuleButton: <class 'sourceeditor.SourceEditor'> (main.py:51)
[CommonSetting][DEBUG] Loading schema value for: com.ubuntu-tweak.tweak/recently-used (common.py:107)
[GSetting][DEBUG] Got the schema_default: [] for key: com.ubuntu-tweak.tweak.recently-used (gsettings.py:21)
[CommonSetting][DEBUG] Loading schema value for: com.ubuntu-tweak.tweak/clips (common.py:107)
[GSetting][DEBUG] Got the schema_default: ['HardwareInfo', 'SystemInfo', 'CleanerInfo', 'UpdateInfo'] for key: com.ubuntu-tweak.tweak.clips (gsettings.py:21)
[ClipPage][DEBUG] Load clips, do_remove: False (__init__.py:137)
[ClipPage][DEBUG] All clips to load: ['HardwareInfo', 'SystemInfo', 'CleanerInfo', 'UpdateInfo'] (__init__.py:145)
[ModuleLoader][INFO] Loading system modules for clips... (__init__.py:54)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] Try to load module: cleanerinfo (__init__.py:159)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] is_supported_distro (__init__.py:238)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] Try to load module: userinfo (__init__.py:159)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] is_supported_distro (__init__.py:238)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] Try to load module: systeminfo (__init__.py:159)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] is_supported_distro (__init__.py:238)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] Try to load module: updateinfo (__init__.py:159)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] is_supported_distro (__init__.py:238)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] Try to load module: hardwareinfo (__init__.py:159)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] is_supported_distro (__init__.py:238)
[ModuleLoader][INFO] Loading user extensions for clips... (__init__.py:64)
[ClipPage][DEBUG] Load clip: HardwareInfo (__init__.py:153)
[ClipPage][DEBUG] Load clip: SystemInfo (__init__.py:153)
[ClipPage][DEBUG] Load clip: CleanerInfo (__init__.py:153)
[ClipPage][DEBUG] Load clip: UpdateInfo (__init__.py:153)
[ClipPage][DEBUG] Overview page: setup_recently_used, 6 used items found (__init__.py:168)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] is_supported_distro (__init__.py:238)
[ModuleLoader][INFO] Loading module "LoginSettings" for "tweaks"... (__init__.py:118)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] is_supported_distro (__init__.py:238)
[ModuleLoader][INFO] Loading module "Misc" for "tweaks"... (__init__.py:118)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] is_supported_distro (__init__.py:238)
[ModuleLoader][INFO] Loading module "Theme" for "tweaks"... (__init__.py:118)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] is_supported_distro (__init__.py:238)
[ModuleLoader][INFO] Loading module "Sound" for "tweaks"... (__init__.py:118)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] is_supported_distro (__init__.py:238)
[ModuleLoader][INFO] Loading module "Fonts" for "tweaks"... (__init__.py:118)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] is_supported_distro (__init__.py:238)
[ModuleLoader][INFO] Loading module "Nautilus" for "tweaks"... (__init__.py:118)
[CommonSetting][DEBUG] Loading schema value for: com.ubuntu-tweak.janitor/auto-scan (common.py:107)
[CommonSetting][DEBUG] Try to get type for value: [('name', 'plugins'), ('type', 'as')] (common.py:147)
[CommonSetting][DEBUG] Try to get type for value: [('name', 'auto-scan'), ('type', 'b')] (common.py:147)
[CommonSetting][DEBUG] Try to get type for value: [('name', 'janitor-view-width'), ('type', 'i')] (common.py:147)
[GSetting][DEBUG] Got the schema_default: True for key: com.ubuntu-tweak.janitor.auto-scan (gsettings.py:21)
[CommonSetting][DEBUG] Loading schema value for: com.ubuntu-tweak.janitor/plugins (common.py:107)
[GSetting][DEBUG] Got the schema_default: [] for key: com.ubuntu-tweak.janitor.plugins (gsettings.py:21)
[CommonSetting][DEBUG] Loading schema value for: com.ubuntu-tweak.janitor/janitor-view-width (common.py:107)
[GSetting][DEBUG] Got the schema_default: 0 for key: com.ubuntu-tweak.janitor.janitor-view-width (gsettings.py:21)
[CommonSetting][DEBUG] Loading schema value for: com.ubuntu-tweak.tweak/clips (common.py:107)
[GSetting][DEBUG] Got the schema_default: ['HardwareInfo', 'SystemInfo', 'CleanerInfo', 'UpdateInfo'] for key: com.ubuntu-tweak.tweak.clips (gsettings.py:21)
[CommonSetting][DEBUG] Loading schema value for: com.ubuntu-tweak.tweak/tweaks (common.py:107)
[GSetting][DEBUG] Got the schema_default: [] for key: com.ubuntu-tweak.tweak.tweaks (gsettings.py:21)
[CommonSetting][DEBUG] Loading schema value for: com.ubuntu-tweak.tweak/admins (common.py:107)
[GSetting][DEBUG] Got the schema_default: [] for key: com.ubuntu-tweak.tweak.admins (gsettings.py:21)
[CommonSetting][DEBUG] Loading schema value for: com.ubuntu-tweak.janitor/plugins (common.py:107)
[GSetting][DEBUG] Got the schema_default: [] for key: com.ubuntu-tweak.janitor.plugins (gsettings.py:21)
[CommonSetting][DEBUG] Loading schema value for: com.ubuntu-tweak.tweak/last-clip-location (common.py:107)
[GSetting][DEBUG] Got the schema_default:  for key: com.ubuntu-tweak.tweak.last-clip-location (gsettings.py:21)
[CommonSetting][DEBUG] Loading schema value for: com.ubuntu-tweak.janitor/auto-scan (common.py:107)
[GSetting][DEBUG] Got the schema_default: True for key: com.ubuntu-tweak.janitor.auto-scan (gsettings.py:21)
[widgets][DEBUG] Connect the setting notify to on_value_changed: com.ubuntu-tweak.janitor.auto-scan (widgets.py:35)
[widgets][DEBUG] Set the swtich to: True (widgets.py:97)
[gui.containers][DEBUG] There are totally 2 columns (containers.py:117)
[gui.containers][DEBUG] Found item: (<Label object at 0x9656eb4 (GtkLabel at 0x973c038)>, <Switch object at 0x9656bbc (ubuntutweak+gui+widgets+Switch at 0x949c9b0)>) (containers.py:184)
[gui.containers][DEBUG] Attach widget: <Label object at 0x9656eb4 (GtkLabel at 0x973c038)> to Grid: 0,1,1,1
 (containers.py:233)
[gui.containers][DEBUG] Set the widget(<Switch with key: auto-scan>) Align START (containers.py:220)
[gui.containers][DEBUG] Attach widget: <Switch with key: auto-scan> to Grid: 1,1,1,1
 (containers.py:233)
[CommonSetting][DEBUG] Loading schema value for: com.ubuntu-tweak.tweak/recently-used (common.py:107)
[GSetting][DEBUG] Got the schema_default: [] for key: com.ubuntu-tweak.tweak.recently-used (gsettings.py:21)
[ClipPage][DEBUG] on_recently_scrolled_window_size_allocate, max_height: 380 (__init__.py:201)
[CommonSetting][DEBUG] Loading schema value for: com.ubuntu-tweak.tweak/window-size (common.py:107)
[GSetting][DEBUG] Got the schema_default: (-1, -1) for key: com.ubuntu-tweak.tweak.window-size (gsettings.py:21)
[ClipPage][DEBUG] on_recently_scrolled_window_size_allocate, max_height: 380 (__init__.py:201)
[app][INFO] select_target_feature: janitor (main.py:378)
[app][DEBUG] on_overview_button_toggled and widget.active is: False (main.py:575)
[app][DEBUG] on_janitor_button_toggled and widget.active is: True (main.py:575)
[app][DEBUG] Feature janitor is not in self.navigation_dict (main.py:580)
[Janitor][INFO] Auto scan status: True (__init__.py:395)
[ModuleLoader][INFO] Loading system modules for janitor... (__init__.py:54)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] Try to load module: opera_plugin (__init__.py:159)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] is_supported_distro (__init__.py:238)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] is_supported_distro (__init__.py:238)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] Try to load module: thumbnailcache_plugin (__init__.py:159)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] is_supported_distro (__init__.py:238)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] is_supported_distro (__init__.py:238)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] Try to load module: autoremoval_plugin (__init__.py:159)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] is_supported_distro (__init__.py:238)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] Try to load module: empathy_plugin (__init__.py:159)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] is_supported_distro (__init__.py:238)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] is_supported_distro (__init__.py:238)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] Try to load module: gwibber_plugin (__init__.py:159)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] is_supported_distro (__init__.py:238)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] is_supported_distro (__init__.py:238)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] Try to load module: googleearth_plugin (__init__.py:159)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] is_supported_distro (__init__.py:238)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] is_supported_distro (__init__.py:238)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] Try to load module: softwarecenter_plugin (__init__.py:159)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] is_supported_distro (__init__.py:238)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] is_supported_distro (__init__.py:238)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] Try to load module: oldkernel_plugin (__init__.py:159)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] is_supported_distro (__init__.py:238)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] Try to load module: mozilla_plugin (__init__.py:159)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] is_supported_distro (__init__.py:238)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] is_supported_distro (__init__.py:238)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] is_supported_distro (__init__.py:238)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] is_supported_distro (__init__.py:238)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] Try to load module: packageconfigs_plugin (__init__.py:159)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] is_supported_distro (__init__.py:238)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] Try to load module: aptcache_plugin (__init__.py:159)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] is_supported_distro (__init__.py:238)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] is_supported_distro (__init__.py:238)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] Try to load module: chrome_plugin (__init__.py:159)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] is_supported_distro (__init__.py:238)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] is_supported_distro (__init__.py:238)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] is_supported_distro (__init__.py:238)
[ModuleLoader][INFO] Loading user extensions for janitor... (__init__.py:64)
[OldKernelPlugin][DEBUG] the current_kernel_version is 3.2.0-40 (oldkernel_plugin.py:25)
[Janitor][DEBUG] left_view_width is: 235, max_janitor_view_width is: 233 (__init__.py:410)
[Janitor][DEBUG] on_move_handle: 237 (__init__.py:324)
[GSetting][DEBUG] The the value for type: None and value: 237 (gsettings.py:52)
[Janitor][DEBUG] do_scan_task for mozilla_plugin for status: True (__init__.py)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] is_supported_distro (__init__.py:238)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] Try to load module: aptcache_plugin (__init__.py:159)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] is_supported_distro (__init__.py:238)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] is_supported_distro (__init__.py:238)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] Try to load module: chrome_plugin (__init__.py:159)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] is_supported_distro (__init__.py:238)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] is_supported_distro (__init__.py:238)
[ModuleLoader][DEBUG] is_supported_distro (__init__.py:238)
[ModuleLoader][INFO] Loading user extensions for janitor... (__init__.py:64)
[OldKernelPlugin][DEBUG] the current_kernel_version is 3.2.0-40 (oldkernel_plugi
n.py:25)
[Janitor][DEBUG] left_view_width is: 235, max_janitor_view_width is: 233 (__init
__.py:410)
[Janitor][DEBUG] on_move_handle: 237 (__init__.py:324)
[GSetting][DEBUG] The the value for type: None and value: 237 (gsettings.py:52)
[Janitor][DEBUG] do_scan_task for mozilla_plugin for status: True (__init__.py:5
68)
[Janitor][INFO] Scan cruft for plugin: FirefoxCachePlugin (__init__.py:571)
[Janitor][DEBUG] scroll_to_cell: 0 (__init__.py:434)
[Janitor][DEBUG] Disconnect the cleaned signal, or it will clean many times: moz
illa_plugin (__init__.py:623)
[Janitor][DEBUG] total_count is: 1 (__init__.py:634)
[Janitor][DEBUG] do_scan_task for thumbnailcache_plugin for status: True (__init
__.py:568)
[Janitor][INFO] Scan cruft for plugin: ThumbnailCachePlugin (__init__.py:571)
[Janitor][DEBUG] scroll_to_cell: 1 (__init__.py:434)
[Janitor][DEBUG] Disconnect the cleaned signal, or it will clean many times: thu
mbnailcache_plugin (__init__.py:623)
[Janitor][DEBUG] total_count is: 3 (__init__.py:634)
[Janitor][DEBUG] do_scan_task for softwarecenter_plugin for status: True (__init
__.py:568)
[Janitor][INFO] Scan cruft for plugin: SoftwareCenterCachePlugin (__init__.py:57
1)
[Janitor][DEBUG] scroll_to_cell: 2 (__init__.py:434)
**
Gtk:ERROR:/build/buildd/gtk+3.0-3.4.2/./gtk/gtktreestore.c:597:gtk_tree_store_ge
t_path: assertion failed: (G_NODE (iter->user_data)->parent != NULL)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: I was used Y-PPA-Manager. I searched "Ubuntu Tweak" in

Comment: I was used Y-PPA-Manager and Synaptic Package Manager: (1) I searched "Ubuntu Tweak" in "Search In All Launchpad PPAs" section; (2) I chose Tualatrix and clicked "Add Selected PPA"; (3) Installed it through Synaptic.

Comment: Ok. Did you try reinstalling?

Comment: Yes, I reinstalled via Synaptic but the problem persist. Then I tried to completely remove, then installed it again, and end up with same result. I didn't update or installing any new package before this just happen this morning.

Comment: Open `ubuntu-tweak` using the terminal and redo the steps. Post whatever is printed on the terminal.

Comment: it happening from the last update ubuntu-tweak has...same here

Answer (score 0):

**Delete the Ubuntu Tweak profile.**

1. Go to the **Home Folder**
2. Press **CTRL & H** to view hidden files
3. Click on the folder **.config**
4. Find the folder **ubuntu-tweak** & delete it

Now restart Ubuntu Tweak as normal, all you have done is to reset Ubuntu Tweak to how it was first installed.  You will not have lost any valuable information it's just a quick and easy way of resetting the program.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't worked with me. The only change occur is the Ubuntu Tweak become more responsive (faster loading). It still shutting down itself. Its even shutting down right after I clicked what option to be cleaned after choose janitor (as I clicked Apt Cache and suddenly Ubuntu Tweak closed itself).

Comment: It seems like the last update (22 April '13) has resolve the problem. I still don't know what the actual problem was, but after I updated Ubuntu Tweak this morning it began to run smoothly again.